# How to add delay to shooting on keypress

Tags: c#, xna

I'm making a space shooter and I'm wondering how to make a delay with the shooting instead of spamming the space bar thanks :)

```
public void Shoot()
    {
        Bullets newBullet = new Bullets(Content.Load<Texture2D>("PlayerBullet"));
        newBullet.velocity = new Vector2((float)Math.Cos(rotation), (float)Math.Sin(rotation)) * 5f;
        newBullet.position = playerPosition + playerVelocity + newBullet.velocity * 5;
        newBullet.isVisible = true;

        if (bullets.Count() >= 0)
            bullets.Add(newBullet);
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you want to use XNA's `GameTime` property.  Whenever you shoot a bullet you should record the time it happened as the current `GameTime.ElapsedGameTime` value.

This is a `TimeSpan` so you could compare it like the following:

```
// Create a readonly variable which specifies how often the user can shoot.  Could be moved to a game settings area
private static readonly TimeSpan ShootInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);

// Keep track of when the user last shot.  Or null if they have never shot in the current session.
private TimeSpan? lastBulletShot;

protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    if (???) // input logic for detecting the spacebar goes here
    {
        // if we got here it means the user is trying to shoot
        if (lastBulletShot == null || gameTime.ElapsedGameTime - (TimeSpan)lastBulletShot >= ShootInterval)
        {
            // Allow the user to shoot because he either has not shot before or it's been 1 second since the last shot.
            Shoot();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Updated with a fix to the logic.

Comment: Thanks :D i have not fixed it yet but this has taught me stuff :)

Answer (score 0):

You can have a counter that counts the number of frames since the last shot.

```
int shootCounter = 0;
```

...

```
if(shootCounter > 15)
{
    Shoot();
    shootcounter = 0;
}
else
{
    shootcounter++;
}
```

If you want to go more advanced, you can use the `gameTime` that the default update method normally gives you to keep track of how much times has passed since you've last shot.

Comment: Just fyi: the `Update` method in xna is _supposedly_ called 60 times a second, but it can lag sometimes. And the update call is totally different call rate than the `Draw` method, so this would be more "ticks" than "frames". But not a big deal, just saying.

Comment: It kinda is a big deal if people with faster computers can shoot faster :)